# Swashbuckler/Swagger ignores Scheme setting

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckler ver. 5.6.0 in webapi project
configuration says:
 c.Schemes(new[] { "https" });

Despite of this, when I access the swagger documentation page for my site, 
it tries to load: 
http://{swagger-docs-url}/swagger/v1, instead of https, and fails because of mixed content

What am I doing wrong here?
Can th

Answer (score 0):

The `c.Schemes(new[] { "https" });` in the configuration only impacts the generated swagger:

That will force the following output:

```
 {
   "swagger": "2.0",
   "info": {
     "version": "V1",
     "title": "Swagger_Test",
   },
   "host": "yourhost.azurewebsites.net",
   "schemes": [
     "https"
   ],
```

Your question is not complete but I believe that what you are looking for is the rootUrl: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#rooturl

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Swashbuckle will detect Uri on host and use the Uri Scheme / port as your  `{swagger-docs-url}` , so if your host running on HTTP it only got HTTP, you can custom the rooturl to fix it.

```
//SwaggerConfig.cs
config.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RootUrl(ResolveBasePath);
    c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });
}

internal static string ResolveBasePath(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    //fix for Cloudflare Flexible SSL and localhost test
    var scheme = message.RequestUri.Host.IndexOf("localhost") > -1 ? "http://" : "https://";
    return scheme + message.RequestUri.Authority;
}
```

I have a site using Cloudflare Flexible SSL, server running on HTTP but inbound connection to Cloudflare was HTTPS, so I need to force the Uri scheme as HTTPS, unless I test on my localhost.